# Does ExceptionHub break Selenium's wait_for_page_to_load command

Tags: selenium, exceptionhub

I just added ExceptionHub (a javascript error tracking service) to our website, but all my selenium tests are failing now. When I look at the selenium output, it says it timed out in waitForPageToLoad command. If I run the test locally, I see that the page loads up fine, so I'm not really sure why selenium keeps waiting. Has anyone else managed to get ExceptionHub working with selenium?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar problems with UserVoice. Often the rest of the page is loaded but still waiting for UserVoice and the test will time out.

It might help if you don't start loading ExceptionHub until the rest of the page is loaded. Of course that would mean you can't catch any javascript errors during page load...